# Could you help me with this simple kwarg example in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing to use kwargs and have a trouble.
This is the python3 code :

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['city'])

a = {'phone':'0101', 'city':'Daejeon'}
b = B(a)
```

But, there is an error like below :

```
    b = B(a)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Is there something wrong in my code?
I think that I just exactly follow the tutorial....

Answer (score 0):

Keyword arguments are not passed that way.

```
obj1 = B(phone='0101', city='Daejeon')
obj2 = B(**a)
```

Comment: a = {'phone':'0101', 'city':'Daejeon'}
b = B(**a) still valid right ?

Comment: @Rockybilly: Yes. There is no requirement to assign it to `obj2`.